# Redirect from SSL for non-ssl pages

Tags: redirect, lighttpd

I'm trying to force SSL and non-SSL on certain pages of my site with redirects in the Lighttpd config file.  I have redirects to SSL working fine:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "www.site.com:80" {
     url.redirect = ( "(login|register/payment|resetpassword|account/password)" => "https://www.site.com/$1" )
}
```

And now I'm trying to go the other way around but I can't get the pattern to hit right (had a copy working fine under apache with .htaccess):

```
$HTTP["host"] == "www.site.com:443" {
     url.redirect = ( "!(login|register/payment|resetpassword|account/password|images|css|javascript|minify/minify.php|states)" => "http://www.site.com/$1" )
}
```

I've tried many combinations but I usually end up in an endless redirect loop because the second matches all URLs when on the SSL port, or it doesn't trigger at all.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using (?!: instead of !( for a negative match.

```
 url.redirect = ( "(?!:login|register/payment|resetpassword|account/password|images|css|javascript|minify/minify.php|states)" => "http://www.site.com/$1" )
```